# LLVM - Load variable from pointer with offset

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a value, let's call it `v`, of `Type i8**` which points to the first element of an array. If I want to get the value that is the variable of first element of the array I can use `Builder.CreateLoad(v);`. If I want to get the second element of the array is there a command like the `CreateLoad()` one, but with an offset?

I have tried adding an integer to `v`, but it hasn't worked (for some obvious reason i don't know). Also I have tried using `Builder.CreateGEP(v, Vector<Value *>{ c64(0), c64(1) });`, but it also doesn't work (`c64` creates a constant).

Can you help?

Comment: You need `getlelementptr` instruction with proper pointer type (`[123 x i8]*`).

Comment: Something like this ?:
```Builder.CreateGEP(ArrayType::get(i8, 123), p.first, Vector<Value *>{ c32(0), c32(1) })```
or this:
```Builder.CreateGEP(PointerType::get(ArrayType::get(i8, 123),0), p.first, Vector<Value *>{ c32(0), c32(1) })```
neither works

Comment: You can't add an int to a pointer because LLVM doesn't do implicit casts, generating the right casts is your job, and you decide most of what "right" means. Generally, life with LLVM is happier if types are first-class citizens in your code, ie. the type for `v` and the type you use to make your GEP are related in your code, not generated by mostly-independent calls to LLVM. I can't guess what "neither works" means, so I have no comment on that.

Comment: What I meant with "neither works" is that both commands that I wrote above generate a runtime error (which I can post if it'll help).
So what you are saying is that I need to cast the type ```i8**``` to a matrix before calling ```CreateGEP```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution. If `v` is a array, `Builder.CreateGEP(v, Vector<Value *>{ c64(0), c64(5) })` loads correctly the 6th element of v. If v is a pointer to a matrix (i8**) then what worked for me was:
`Builder.CreateGEP(Builder.CreateLoad(p.first), c64(5))`, which correctly loads the 6th element of the array which `v` points to.
(function `c64()` creates a 64bit int constant)